# AS3 MouseEvents

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

I'm doing a top-down view game. Is a really simple one in fact. The character moves when the player click in the screen. But, I have a fire button too.
I want know how I can disable the mouse from click when player press the button. Because when this happen the character moves to button spot.

Here's my code:

```
var walk = false;
var goX = player.x;
var goY = player.y;
var speed = 10;
var dir = "down";

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, btn1);

function btn1(event:MouseEvent):void
{

fireBullet();

}


function fireBullet():void {
var playerDirection:String;
if(player.scaleX < 0){
    playerDirection = "left";
} else if(player.scaleX > 0){
    playerDirection = "right";

} 
if(char.scaleY < 0){
    playerDirection = "up";
} else if(char.scaleY > 0){
    playerDirection = "down";
}

var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x, player.y, playerDirection);
stage.addChild(bullet);
}



function loop(Event)
{

if (walk == true)
{
player.w.play();
}
else
{
player.w.gotoAndStop(1);
}

player.gotoAndStop(dir);


if ((goY-speed)>player.y)
{
player.y +=  speed;
dir = "down";
}
else if ((goY+speed)<player.y)
{
player.y -=  speed;
dir = "up";
}
if ((goX-speed)>player.x)
{
player.x +=  speed;
dir = "right";
}
else if ((goX+speed)<player.x)
{
player.x -=  speed;
dir = "left";
}

if ((goY-speed)>player.y || (goY+speed)<player.y || (goX-speed)>player.x || (goX+speed)                  <player.x){
walk = true;
} else {  
 walk =false
}
}

 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, set);

function set(MouseEvent){
goX=mouseX
goY=mouseY}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a button on the keyboard? Like when you hold down spacebar the walking gets disabled?

Comment: No. Is a virtual button which I achieve using MouseEvent - and I also use MouseEvent to move the character along the screen -, 'cuz I'm doing this game to a touch device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply, using the concept of `target` can be handled as follows.

try this:

```
function set(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      var target = e.target;

      //ex) if(target is MovieClip) return;
      if(target is <#your fire button type#>) return;

      goX=mouseX;
      goY=mouseY;
}
```

what is different "target" vs "currentTarget"?

> - **target**: the object that fired event.
> - **currentTarget**: the object that you applied the listener to.

Answer (score 2):

Since mouse events bubble up the display list and you have a listener added to the stage, when the user presses a button, you need to stop the event from propagating.

In order to achieve this, in the button handler, you would need to the call `stopImmediatPropagation` method. So, your btn1 method would look like this:

```
function btn1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fireBullet();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

This way, you prevent the click event from bubbling all the way up to the stage, in turn causing the stage's click handler to be called.

Hope this helps. Have a great day.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But unfortunately not work for me, my character still going to the button spot.

Comment: I see. Then what this means is that there is probably another fault in your code somewhere. Maybe the 'loop' method, which is called on enter frame, still translates the player, even though the button click event doesn't bubble.